# What is the correct way to use flex in table headers?

Tags: html, css

In the following table I require in th tags to see their content in the opposite ends

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Col 1</span>^</th>
            <th><span>Col 2</span>^</th>
            <th><span>Col 3</span>^</th>
            <th><span>Col 4</span>^</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When trying to do it using flex I get unexpected behavior

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* here is the change */
th {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Column 1</span>^</th>
            <th><span>Column 2</span>^</th>
            <th><span>Column 3</span>^</th>
            <th><span>Column 4</span>^</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The expected result is obtained but the headers lose their position

What is the correct way to use flex in table headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving `display:flex` to **th** will make it lose its table sturcture,Because by default all **th** are `display: table-cell;` so changing that is not recommended

This is what you mean?

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.d-flex{display:flex;}
.ml-auto{margin-left:auto;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="d-flex">Column 1
          <div class="ml-auto">^</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="d-flex">Column 1
          <div class="ml-auto">^</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="d-flex">Column 1
          <div class="ml-auto">^</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="d-flex">Column 1
          <div class="ml-auto">^</div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Nice example, all that is needed is to add a div

Comment: Are you looking for other answer or u still have doubt? I have added reason in the answer so please check and confirm answer..!